# Select last HTML class using "document.getElementsByClassName"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to select the last of a specific class in HTML using Javascript. I can't seem to find a method that I understand by googling.

Preferebly using `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Do you know how to select the last item in a list?

Comment: You mean the last element returned in the [`HTMLCollection`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned by [`getElementsByClassName`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)? Have you tried searching for an approach that returns the last item in an array? That’s the same thing. What _have_ you tried? What don’t you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the last element from the [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned by `.getElementsByClassName`.

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
console.log(elements[elements.length-1]);
```

```html
<div class="a">hello1</div>
<div class="a">hello2</div>
<div class="a">hello3</div>
<div class="a">hello4</div>
<div class="b">hello5</div>
```